# stack level too deep with `puts response` in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

Having a strange problem with rspec and rails in controller tests. Whenever we add `puts response` inside a spec, it outputs lots of these

```
200
{"Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}
200
{"Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}
200
{"Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}
200
{"Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}
```

and then fails with `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`. Inspecting the response via pry works great, printing other stuff also works fine.

Upgrading to latest rspec (2.11) does not make a difference. We noticed that the puts calls `to_a` on the response, which returns an array of `[@status, @header, self]`, so somehow it causes this strange recursion?

**update**: here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/3742800) with the code + spec

Comment: Yes, it calls your controller code recursively, posting your code might help.

Comment: but why would `puts response` call the controller code recursively? We are accessing the `response` object, not the controller... or I'm probably missing something here

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing now, just curious, why not use p or ap?

Comment: good question. In a way, this is not our main problem. There's no real reason/need to do `puts response` in our specs. Pry does a great job if we need to inspect stuff. However, I am investigating another intermittent problem where we are getting `stack level too deep` error which has nothing to do with puts. I have a hunch these problems are related, and since this is easily reproducible I'm trying to focus on this `puts` problem if that makes sense...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you've run into a bug in rack.  `[rack_response].flatten` goes into an infinite loop.  See these issues for more info:

- https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/601
- https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/166
- https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/419

The solution is to not set any expectations on the response object itself, instead, set expectations on the status, headers or body individually, e.g.:

```
last_response.status.should eq(200)
last_response.body.should include("some text")
last_response.headers.should include("Content-Type" => "text/plain")
```

Comment: Thanks @Myron. It certainly feels like a bug. I can see that returning an array which includes **self** will obviously cause an inifinite loop when called with something like `puts`. We do actually only access `response.status` normally, I wonder why we bumped into this `stack level too deep` issue intermittently even without `puts`ing the response... However I'm aware this wasn't the original question.